# Why does RefCell not have the same scoping as regular references?

Tags: rust, scope

I can write the following function `f` and the code compiles as I would expect:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct A {
    data: HashMap<u32, B>,
}

struct B {
    val: Option<u32>,
}

impl A {
    fn f(&mut self, key: u32) {
        let data = &self.data[&key];
        match data.val {
            Some(value) => panic!("{}", value),
            None => self.data.remove(&key),
        };
    }
}
```

Here `key` is checked out first immutably `&self.data[&key]`, and then again mutably (`self.data.remove(&key)`), but the compiler allows this, likely because `data` is never used after the mutable checkout.

However, if I then use a `RefCell` rather than just a regular ref, I get a compile time error, even though the logic is otherwise (seemingly) the same:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct A {
    data: HashMap<u32, RefCell<B>>,
}

struct B {
    val: Option<u32>,
}

impl A {
    fn f(&mut self, key: u32) {
        let data = self.data[&key].borrow();
        match data.val {
            Some(value) => panic!("{}", value),
            None => self.data.remove(&key),
        };
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.data` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:17:21
   |
14 |         let data = self.data[&key].borrow();
   |                    --------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
17 |             None => self.data.remove(&key),
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
18 |         };
19 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow might be used here, when `data` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Ref<'_, B>`
```

My guess is that the compiler isn't able to determine that I finished with `data`, due to it being a `RefCell` and thus checked at runtime, but if that's the case, is there any way I can 'check in' the value that I borrowed, since its no longer needed? Or is my only option to let it go out of scope? (Which is fine, for this small example, but aesthetically displeasing with larger ones.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My guess is that the compiler isn't able to determine that I finished with *data*

The compiler *could*, but it chooses not to, in order to avoid worse surprises. The specific rule here is that

- values of types which have `Drop` code (such as `std::cell::Ref`) always have that code run *at the end of scope*,
- which means that any borrows held by those values also extend to end of scope.

Drop timing/ordering matters because it can have side effects, so the compiler keeps it predictable.

> is there any way I can 'check in' the value that I borrowed, since its no longer needed?

Explicitly drop it. Change your `match` like this and it will compile:

```rust
None => {
    drop(data);
    self.data.remove(&key);
}
```

Now the compiler sees that `data` no longer exists and is no longer borrowing `self.data`, so it lets you borrow `self.data` exclusively afterward.

Comment: Neat. I suppose in that case, you could also force the drop by fetching `val` in an isolated scope? Something like `match { let data = self.data[&key].borrow(); data.val } { ... }` ?

Comment: @flakes Yes, but the cases where that works are also often cases where you can use `Cell` instead of `RefCell` anyway (since you're not taking a reference to the content.