# Linked list stack overflow

Tags: rust, linked-list

Consider this simple linked list implementation:

```rust
enum Cons<T> {
    Empty,
    Cons(T, Box<Cons<T>>),
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = Cons::Empty;
    for i in 1..1_000_000 {
        list = Cons::Cons(i, Box::new(list));
    }
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4df2566f285b4a47ea1073145d19f56c)</sup>

Why does it overflow the stack?

Comment: Hint: add `impl<T> Drop for Cons<T>{ fn drop(&mut self) println!("Dropping"); } }`

Comment: You should check out [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists, 2.7 Drop](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-drop.html)

Comment: I'm inferring from your hints that rust implements drop recursively? Can you just say that if it's true?

Comment: Not always, but what drop glue do you think should be generated for `Cons<T>` in the variant `Cons`? I.e. if your datastructure is recursive, how would you in general generate the drop glue?

Comment: I don't know, but now I have a lot of questions about how to represent a graph in Rust. Does Rust die when the largest cycle exceeds a certain length? When the smallest cycle? When a cycle is too long as determined by grabbing the first element in the list of neighbors?

Comment: You could have a flat list of objects and then define the relationships using weak references. You'll need to manage dropping expired references, but it avoids issues with the recursive drop logic and a lot of ownership issues introduced by cycles.

Comment: Well, it depends on how you implement your graph.

Comment: Also see https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-06-reference-cycles.html#preventing-reference-cycles-turning-an-rct-into-a-weakt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It overflows the stack on trying to drop `list`. The drop glue generated by Rust simply drops all fields in order, so it's going to look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
match self {
    Self::Empty => {},
    Self::Cons(a, b) => {
        Drop::drop(&mut a);
        Drop::drop(&mut b);
    }
}
```

The call `Drop::drop(&mut b);` is going to recurse to this same drop code (indirectly through `Box`'s drop code), and it will continue to recurse 1,000,000 times in order to drop the entire list. Though, note that it will actually create 2,000,000 stack frames as `Cons`'s drop glue and `Box`'s drop implementation are going to call each other. This overflows the stack. (Note that tailcall optimization can't even be performed, because `b` is a box -- the box needs to be destroyed after the inner `Cons` is dropped.)

Fixing this seems straightforward but requires a few hacks since you can't move out of values that implement `Drop`.

The basic approach is to implement `Drop` manually and recursively drop the structure using iteration instead of recursive function calls.  To help with this, we can create a method that will "steal" an existing `Cons<T>` leaving it `Empty`.  We can use this to pull the `Cons<T>` value out of the box without actually moving it out as far as Rust is concerned.

```
impl<T> Cons<T> {
    pub fn take(&mut self) -> Cons<T> {
        std::mem::replace(self, Self::Empty)
    }
}
```

Easy enough.  Now we can implement `Drop` around this method.

Notably, we have to check for the non-recursive cases first (`self` is `Empty` or is a `Cons` whose box is also `Empty`) to avoid accidental infinite recursion<sup>1</sup>.  Once we know we have at least one level of recursion, we can simply loop forward in the structure, `take()`-ing the next item into our iteration variable:

```
impl<T> Drop for Cons<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        match self {
            Self::Empty => return,
            Self::Cons(_, boxed) if matches!(**boxed, Self::Empty) => return,
            _ => {}
        };

        let mut v = self.take();

        while let Self::Cons(_, boxed) = &mut v {
            v = boxed.take();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, whenever Rust's generated drop glue gets ahold of a `Cons` value, it will always either be `Empty` or be a `Cons` whose box is `Empty`.

---

<sup>1</sup> The line `let mut v = self.take();` will cause infinite recursion of our `drop()` implementation if we don't first check for the terminating cases. It will unconditionally create a new `Cons<T>` value, which must be dropped, but `drop()` will then unconditionally create *another* `Cons<T>` when it tries to drop that one. The `match` block detects the terminating cases to avoid creating a new `Cons<T>` when Rust's own drop glue will correctly handle the value without recursing more than once.

Comment: How does this work memory wise? Does each object go out of scope and get dropped after each while loop iteration, or does this end up creating N values of `Cons::Empty` which are all dropped together at the end of the function?

Comment: @flakes `v = boxed.take();` takes the `Cons` value out of `boxed`, drops `v`, then stores the taken value in `v`. So values are dropped during iteration. (If they were all dropped at the end, there would have to be some kind of hidden `Vec` storing them all, which Rust isn't going to implicitly create.)

Comment: I was reading this explanation yesterday that values with custom Drop methods only get dropped after they go out of scope https://stackoverflow.com/a/77241556/3280538 . This case is kind of tricky because `v` is created initially in a higher level scope, and it's being re-assigned with a new value. I guess in this case, re-assigning the variable counts as it leaving scope immediately?

Comment: Ah, yep that is whats happening, proved it to myself! https://gist.github.com/cal-pratt/b9c8863d119fc59c7abd9be5fb5d1883 Thanks

Comment: @flakes Correct. Values are dropped when the scope ends, but they can be dropped earlier for multiple reasons. One is replacing the value in an existing binding; the prior value in that binding is dropped.

Comment: This is great, but I actually did mean "why does the default implementation overflow the stack". What is the default implementation?

Comment: @Test Because the generated drop glue drops values recursively, which means it's going to call itself 1 million times in your example code.

Comment: @Test I've amended my answer to include an explanation of why the stack overflow happens.